# 'Where' Query Statement in Google Sheets

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I don't deal with excel or spreadsheets very often but I have a Google Sheets doc with 4 columns.

```
User_ID | Referred_by_user_id | Votes | Referral Votes
```

Each user can get many votes. But they also get 20% bonus votes for any votes their referrals get.

Is there a formula I can use here to help with this dynamically? I basically want to say:

```
Add RowX Votes to RowY Referral Votes WHERE RowX Referred_by_user_id MATCHES RowY User_ID
```

Does such a thing exist in Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* if layout is as in the image what you want is:

```
 =IF(B2=A3,C2+D3,"")
```

copied down to suit.

[image: SO30584760 example]

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't know if they crossed over

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array formula to be entered in D2 - please advise if it doesn't achieve what you are after.

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A),))`

Comment: Yes, I think based on your answer, we have a different understanding of the question, and mine may well be the incorrect one. I was assuming that a user would get the "referral votes" when his/her ID (in the A column) appears elsewhere in the "referred" column (the B column). So in your example, neither user "a" or "b" would get *any* referral votes, because they don't appear in column B. If user "D" appeared somewhere in column A, he/she would get 3 referral votes. But I reiterate, I might be misunderstanding entirely, and I figure putting a wrong answer up often leads to a solution. :-)